# check the checkbox when row is clicked angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-material

I tried everything but cannot get the desired answer.
 How can i make the whole row clickable and when i click checbox should be checked and row should be active any idea

**Here is my html file**

```
<section class="others" >
<div class="sub-header">Others</div>
<p class="text-center" *ngIf="otherTests.length === 0">No Tests Available</p>
<app-custom-accordion [closeOthers]="true">
<ngb-panel [disabled]="true" *ngFor="let testPanel of otherTests let i = index;" id="{{testPanel.Id}}" [title]="testPanel.Name">
  <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
    <div class="action-items">
      <span class="material-icons fav" [class.favorited]="testPanel.Favorite" (click)="onFavoriteClick(testPanel)"></span>
      <span class="icon-set" [ngClass]="{'same-day-2x': isSameDay(testPanel.Code), 'next-day-2x': isNextDay(testPanel.Code)}"></span>
      <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            class="custom-control-input"
            [name]="testPanel.Id + '-' + testPanel.Moniker"
            [ngModel]="panelIds.indexOf(testPanel.Id) > -1"
            (ngModelChange)="onPanelCheckboxUpdate($event, testPanel)"
            [id]="testPanel.Id + '-' + testPanel.Moniker">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      </label>
       </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-panel>
  </app-custom-accordion>
 </section>
```

**this is my panel**

[image]

**Here is my Ts file for checkbox change**

```
public panelIds: Array<number>;

onPanelCheckboxUpdate($event: boolean, panel: TestOrderPanel) {
this.checked = $event
let testPanelIds = panel.Tests.map(test => test.Id);
// Wipe any duplicates
this.panelIds = this.panelIds.filter(
  panelId => panel.Id !== panelId && testPanelIds.indexOf(panelId) === -1
);
this.selectedPanels = this.selectedPanels.filter(
  selectedPanel =>
    panel.Id !== selectedPanel.Id &&
    testPanelIds.indexOf(selectedPanel.Id) === -1
);

if ($event) {
  this.panelIds.push(panel.Id);
  this.selectedPanels.push(panel);
   }
  this.updateSession();
}
```

**This is my app-custom-accordion component**

```
 <div class="card">
 <ng-template ngFor let-panel [ngForOf]="panels">
<div role="tab" id="{{panel.id}}-header" [class]="'card-header ' + 
 (panel.type ? 'card-' + panel.type: type ? 'card-' + type : '')"
  [class.active]="isOpen(panel.id)">
  <a href (click)="!!toggle(panel.id)" [attr.tabindex]=" . 
 (panel.disabled 
  ? '-1' : null)" [attr.aria-expanded]="isOpen(panel.id)"
    [attr.aria-controls]="(isOpen(panel.id) ? panel.id : null)" 
 [attr.aria-disabled]="panel.disabled">{{panel.title}}</a>
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="panel.titleTpl?.templateRef"></ng- 
  template>
  <!-- expansion arrows -->
  <div *ngIf="arrowExpand" (click)="toggle(panel.id)" [attr.aria- 
  expanded]="isOpen(panel.id)">
    <span class="material-icons expand"></span>
  </div>

 </div>
 <div id="{{panel.id}}" role="tabpanel" [attr.aria-labelledby]="panel.id + '-header'" class="card-block" *ngIf="isOpen(panel.id) && panel.contentTpl">
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="panel.contentTpl?.templateRef"></ng-template>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
```

How to change the color of whole row when click on checkbox 
like when checkbox is selected the whole row should be dark or whatever and when unchecked should go to previous color i.e white
can anyone help? thanks

Comment: do one thing add one property to test panel like selected and on click on row/div set it true, and on click of other rows make all selected false and and clicked true

Comment: can you please explain a little bit thanks @JayantPatil

Comment: An example [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com) could help us solve your problem.

Comment: bind your text & checkbox in `<label></label>`'s

Comment: will it do the trick? :D @TusharWalzade